# How do I retrieve all items in an ArangoDB collection using GraphQL

Tags: graphql, arangodb

I am using the [ArangoDB FOXX GraphQL Example](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.3/Manual/Foxx/GraphQL.html) to retrieve data from a couple of collections (each one named the same as the type). Everything is fine when I want to retrieve one item using the _key property, but when I try to retrieve all items in a collection (see diagnosticItems) I receive an error. My schema definition is:

```
export const typeDefs = [`
enum Status {
  up
  down
}

type DiagnosticItem {
  _key: String!
  title: String!
  status: Status
  locationKey: String
  lastUpdatedDate: String

  location: Location @aql(exec: "FOR location in Location filter location._key == @current.locationKey return location")
}

type Location {
  _key: String!
  title: String!
}

type Query {
  diagnosticItem(_key: String!): DiagnosticItem
  diagnosticItems: [DiagnosticItem]
  location(_key: String!): Location
}
`];
```

The full StackBlitz is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/arangodb-graphql).